# ピクセルパーフェクトのやり方が分からず、文章が一文字ずつずれてしまう

Tags: html, css

ピクセルパーフェクトで、サイトの制作をしようとしていますが、
文章の文字一文字一文字の位置を一回一回調節しないと、出来ないのでしょうか？

```
<div class="header-outer">
<p class="header-time"><span class="header-time-second">平日</span>０<span class="header-time-third">８:</span><span class="header-time-fifth">０</span><span class="header-time-fourth">０〜</span><span class="header-time-third">2０:</span>００</p>
<div class="header-content">

header .header-container .header-wrapper-second .header-outer .header-time {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    letter-spacing: -4.3px;
}
header .header-container .header-wrapper-second .header-outer .header-time .header-time-second{
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}

header .header-container .header-wrapper-second .header-outer .header-time .header-time-third{
    letter-spacing: -1.9px;
}


header .header-container .header-wrapper-second .header-outer .header-time .header-time-fourth{
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

header .header-container .header-wrapper-second .header-outer .header-time .header-time-fifth{
    letter-spacing: -4px;
}
```

ここまでしないと位置を揃えることが出来ません。
フォントは見本と同じはずです。

指定しているフォントは游ゴシック体で、CSSには下記のように記入しています。

```
body {
    font-family: "游ゴシック体", YuGothic, "游ゴシック Medium", "Yu Gothic Medium", "游ゴシック", "Yu Gothic", sans-serif;
}
```

検証ツールで確認したところ
レンダリング フォント
Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN—ローカル ファイル（15 件のグリフ）となっています。

**表示結果:**
[image]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: フォントは見本と同じということですが、何を指定していますか？

Comment: フォントは游ゴシックです。　検証ツールを見たところの、レンダリング フォントHiragino Kaku Gothic ProN—ローカル ファイル（15 件のグリフとなっています。

Comment: あと見本はどのように制作データはありますか？イラレであろうがXDであろうが行間や文字間隔の情報が載っていて参考になるかなと思いますが

Comment: あります、テキストYuGothic フォント１２ｐｘです。行間は０です。

Comment: デザインカンフ通りにやってもずれます。

Comment: 別のサイトで答えを教えていただけました。
カンプはアドビのXDやPsやAiなどで作ることが多いですが、これらのアプリケーションはDTPなどweb以外の用途利用も考えられ、フォントのカーニング・スペーシング・トラッキングや禁則処理や半角文字処理など、ブラウザで再現できないような細かいフォントのコントロール機能を実装しているため、コーディングだけで再現するには、一文字一文字、位置を調節する必要があるそうです(正確には、そうまでしても、ブラウザによって表示が変わるので本当の意味でピクセルパーフェクトは、出来ないようです。)。

Comment: @kkk その内容を回答として投稿し、ご自身で解決済みとしていただけたらと。